# Recursively call a method with the same thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-core

I have the following method:

```
public async Task ScrapeObjects(int page = 1)
{
    try
    {
        while (!isObjectSearchCompleted)
        {
            ..do calls..
        }
    }
    catch (HttpRequestException ex)
    {

        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
        ScrapeObjects(page);

        Log.Fatal(ex, ex.Message);
    }
}
```

I call this long running method async and I don't wait for it to finish. Thing is that an exception my occur and in that case I want to handle it. But then I want to start from where I left and with the same thread. At the current state a new thread gets used when I recursively call the method after handling the exception. I would like to keep using the same thread. Is there a way to do so? Thank you!

Comment: Why do you care what threadpool thread gets used for what? also, with IO bound calls these arnt threads at all, they are callbacks from a completion port

Comment: Cause it felt to me like I was not really doing recursion.. because after the Thread.Sleep the second thread starts again with the method.. but the first thread reaches the end of the method. So maybe if I add some logic afterwards it would be executed by the first thread.. and sorry for calling them threads :/

Comment: What does `ScrapeObjects` do? Does it return something? Is the code that searches for objects (the ..do calls.. part) asynchronous?

Comment: Use a queue-system. Enqueue the first page, process the first item in the queue, when you find new links in that page, add them to the queue. Keep processing the first item in the queue like this until the queue is empty. On exceptions, retry the item until you can't/won't (you should have some form of limit).

Comment: I'd also recommend looking into [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly) to handle fault tolerance. It's well documented and made to handle situations like this.

Comment: If the goal is simply to retry the same operation after an exception, why do you not just put the whole thing in a `while(true)` or `while(numberOfAttempts < maxNumberOfAttemps)`, and break out of the loop on success? Frankly, your question is very unclear; it needs more context in the form of a good [mcve] and a more precise explanation of what you've tried and what specifically you need help with.

Comment: This is more like a semi-infinite loop rather than recursion. However recursion could be dangerous because you might hit Stackoverflow exception unconsciously. A while loop is good enough.

Comment: There is nothing in your code that shows us how (or even if) threads are being created. We need a [mcve] to really help you here.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to move the try/catch block inside the `while` loop, and add a counter with the errors occurred, to bail out in case of continuous faulted attempts.

```
public async Task ScrapeObjects()
{
    int failedCount = 0;
    int page = 1;
    while (!isObjectSearchCompleted)
    {
        try
        {
            //..do calls..
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException ex)
        {
            failedCount++;
            if (failedCount < 3)
            {
                Log.Info(ex, ex.Message);
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
            }
            else
            {
                Log.Fatal(ex, ex.Message);
                throw; // or return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As a side note it is generally better to `await Task.Delay` instead of `Thread.Sleep` inside asynchronous methods, to avoid blocking a thread without a reason.

Answer (score 0):

One simple question before you read the long answer below:

**Why you need the same thread? Are you accessing thread static / contextual data?**

If yes, there will be ways to solve that easily than limiting your tasks to run on the same thread.

#### How to limit tasks to run on a single thread

As long as you use async calls on the default synchronization context, and as soon as the code is resumed from an `await`, it is possible that the thread can change after an `await`. This is because the default context schedules tasks to the next available thread in the thread pool. Like in the below case, `before` can be different from `after`:

```
public async Task ScrapeObjects(int page = 1)
{
    var before = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    var after = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
}
```

The only reliable way to guarantee that your code could come back on the same thread is to schedule your async code onto a single threaded synchronization context:

```
class SingleThreadSynchronizationContext : SynchronizationContext
{ 
    private readonly BlockingCollection<Action> _actions = new BlockingCollection<Action>();
    private readonly Thread _theThread;

    public SingleThreadSynchronizationContext()
    {
        _theThread = new Thread(DoWork);
        _theThread.IsBackground = true;
        _theThread.Start();
    }

    public override void Send(SendOrPostCallback d, object state)
    {
        // Send requires run the delegate immediately.
        d(state);
    }

    public override void Post(SendOrPostCallback d, object state)
    {
        // Schedule the action by adding to blocking collection.
        _actions.Add(() => d(state));
    }

    private void DoWork()
    {
        // Keep picking up actions to run from the collection.
        while (!_actions.IsAddingCompleted)
        {
            try
            {
                var action = _actions.Take();
                action();
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException)
            {
                break;
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

And you need to schedule `ScrapeObjects` to the custom context:

```
SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new SingleThreadSynchronizationContext());
await Task.Factory.StartNew(
        () => ScrapeObjects(),
        CancellationToken.None,
        TaskCreationOptions.DenyChildAttach | TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning,
        TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()
).Unwrap();
```

By doing that, all your async code shall be scheduled to the same context, and run by the thread on that context.

**However**

This is typically **dangerous**, as you suddenly lose the ability to use the thread pool. If you block the thread, the entire async operation is blocked, meaning you will have deadlocks.

Comment: I believe that by "same thread" the OP actually means "same task". But I may be wrong.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I think you might want to clarify what the op actually meant. And is that task a `Task` object? There is no point to keep everything on one task object. Because tasks are supposed to be short lived based on the fact they usually run on thread pool thread. If you need long running task, you have to explicitly create one using flags.

Comment: I am not really sure what the OP meant. Hopefully your answer will help to clarify things by getting feedback from the OP.

Comment: Check out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcreationoptions?view=netframework-4.8, the long running flag will give you a dedicated thread which is not from the thread pool. In case you do need long running task, consider use that flag, so you could free up thread pool for all other things.

Comment: I agree with your points. All this stuff is known to me. I am just not sure if the OP is in need for them. They may not be too familiar with threads and tasks and asynchrony in general, and could be quite puzzled with all this advanced stuff with `SingleThreadSynchronizationContext` etc you've thrown at them. 

Comment: Yep. I'd say 99% of the cases they wouldn't want a custom sync context, and really the provided contexts are working just fine for most cases. Only when special cases come in, like UI thread, you might then need a special context. However, by the looks of your code, I don't think that's a case of a custom context. But that's the way you can limit task and children task to ONE thread.

Comment: We don't even know what is the type of the app. If it's a Windows Forms app, it has a single-thread context by default. If it's a console app, needing a single-thread context would be strange and rare.

Comment: WinForm app has a single threaded context but might not suit your case. You probably don't want to execute the mentioned long running thing over onto UI thread because when you have blocking operation, say deserializing a large JSON, the UI will freeze.